# How to use Awk to use a template and save a copy on a remote server?

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following command that I am trying to run. The problem is every time I run the script it says it cannot find the file or directory.

```
awk -v host=$host -v stockcode=$other1 '{sub(/DIGICODE/,host);sub(/SYSMAN/,stockcode); print }' ${web}service/cert.html >> ${web}service/cert_new.html
```

So cert.html is my template, cert_new.html is my desired output file.

${web} is my servers IP address ie "127.0.0.1/test/"
$host and $other1 are local variables inside my bash script.

Now when it runs the output is the following :

***127.0.0.1/test/service/cert_new.html: No such file or directory***

I am not sure if Awk is the best way to go ?

Comment: Are you running this command on your server?  Does the directory where you are running the command have a subdirectory named '127.0.0.1/test'?   If you are running the script on your server, change it to use the absolute path to the template html file and the absolute path to the output html file location.

Comment: Okay I am running it from a PXE boot USB connecting back to my server. 127.0.0.1 is just an example of the IP.

Comment: Are you saying you want your command locally to modify a file on some remote machine with IP address 127.0.0.1 for example? Your problem has nothing to do with awk, btw, you'd have the same problem with any Unix tool - your target file path simply doesn't exist on your local machine where you're running the command. To make changes on a remote machine, google `ssh` as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with `awk`.

To verify this assumption, first run

```
awk -v host="$host" -v stockcode="$other1" '{sub(/DIGICODE/,host);sub(/SYSMAN/,stockcode); print }' ${web}service/cert.html
```

if it produces the expected output you are fine.

Then, verify the directory and eventually the file you are trying to append exist (in the same directory you are expecting to run `awk`)

```
if [[ ! -d "${web}service/" ]]
then
    echo "error"
fi

if [[ ! -f "${web}service/cert_new.html" ]]
then
    echo "file does not exist"
fi
```